# Change focus list of textboxes WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, focus

I have a listbox where the Items are Textboxes. I need to set a key to change the focus to the next textbox and begin the editing of its content.
I have cheated a solution sending Key strokes to achieve what I want, for example:

```
        ((TextBox)listBox1.Items[0]).KeyDown += (object x, KeyEventArgs y) => { 
            if (y.Key == Key.Enter) { 
                InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.TAB); 
                InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.DOWN); 
                InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.TAB); 
            } 
        };
```

I use the library InputSimulator found here  http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/ for that approach.
I know that this is not the correct way to do it so I'm ask how can i achieve the same using the focus methods. I try with the following code but i get "out of range" error that I don't understand:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(new TextBox() { 
                TabIndex=i
            });

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count-1; i++)
        {
            ((TextBox)listBox1.Items[i]).KeyDown += (object x, KeyEventArgs y) => { if (y.Key == Key.Tab) { Keyboard.Focus((TextBox)listBox1.Items[i+1]); } };
        }
        ((TextBox)listBox1.Items[listBox1.Items.Count - 1]).KeyDown += (object x, KeyEventArgs y) => { if (y.Key == Key.Tab) { Keyboard.Focus((TextBox)listBox1.Items[0]); }};

    }
```

Comment: You might find more responses to your question if you cleanup the example code a bit.  Don't inline you statements so much for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a really short answer for you.  In XAML you can use a style to define a common handler for your listboxes...

```
<Window x:Class="Interface.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

  <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
      <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="TextBox_KeyDown"/>
      <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>


  <ListBox Name="lstBoxList">
    <TextBox>ABC</TextBox>
    <TextBox>DEF</TextBox>
    <TextBox>GHI</TextBox>
  </ListBox>

</Window>
```

So you can see all of the text boxes in the list.  The actual handler code will look like this...

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
  {
    // Locate current item.
    int current = lstBoxList.Items.IndexOf(sender);

    // Find the next item, or give up if we are at the end.
    int next = current + 1;
    if (next > lstBoxList.Items.Count - 1) { return; }

    // Focus the item.
    (lstBoxList.Items[next] as TextBox).Focus();
  }
}
```

So the basic concept is that you will locate the current text box in the list.  Then you will find the next one somehow (tags, names, etc.) and focus it explicitly.  Of course you will have to tweak depending on your exact need.

Comment: Perhaps i don't understad yet why my solution is wrong, yours work, so I'm going to use it, thanks.

Comment: Related with the same, I don't know how to set the focus to the first item when the Windows Load. (ListBox1.Items[0] as TextBox).Focus() do not begin the edition immedately. I need to press the Tab key one more time. Could you showme how can i do that?. Note that every TextBox is created dynamically.

Comment: @voodoomsr: I don't think your example is wrong, it is just doing it in a way that isn't exactly stable.  If you want to focus your textboxes when the window loads, try doing it in the Window.Loaded event or similar.  Sorry, but I can't really give more detail here.